# how to show products from a magento store on to the facebook application

Tags: facebook, magento

I would like to create a facebook application which would be an online store. but the catch is that all the data will be retrieved from an existing online store developed on magento.

I understand that there are extensions available for this but i would be thankful if someone can guide me and move me on the right direction on developing my own application .

Thanks

Comment: A good place to start is the Magenot API. You will need to use that to make calls to the Magento store remotely. For instance, you request a specific category to the API and it returns a feed of all of the products in that category. You can then pull that feed into your Facebook app.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/magento_core_api

Comment: @Avisra  thanks for the suggestion, it has moved me to the right direction!